# Custom domain not working after transferring the domain name to different provider

Tags: google-app-engine

A while ago I setup a custom domain for my app engine and all worked fine.
I had to add a TXT record so google could verify I was the owner.

I now transferred my domain name to a different provider and readded the necessary DNS records but it doesn't seem to work anymore.
I now get the message "DNS records could not be found. Certificate activation will retry automatically."

My guess is that I would need to readd the domain name and perform this TXT record check?
I don't find a way to remove everything and start from the beginning.

How could I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Still running into this as well after readding the DNS records google provided. I get the `DNS records could not be found. Certificate activation will retry automatically.` warning.